# Confusion about the probability of being dealt 2 pairs

Tags: probability

There are seemingly three ways to calculate this, and they yield different answers. Please help me understand which way is correct.

1) Having two pairs is choosing 2 ranks (namely A and B) out of 13 ranks. Then we choose two out of four cards for each of the two chosen ranks. Finally, there are 44 remaining cards to choose from that are not rank A and not rank B. And of course, we divide everything by (52 choose 5) because we are choosing 5 cards out of 52 cards.

2)Instead of doing (13 choose 2), it seems to also make sense to do (13 choose 1) x (12 choose 1). Notice that (13 choose 2) is not equal to (13 choose 1)(12 choose 1). Which is correct?

3) Now we can also find the possibility for each card. For the first card, you can choose any card, which is 52/52. For the second card, it needs to be the same rank, and there are 3 left, so that's 3/51. For the third card, it needs to be different rank from the first two cards, so that's 48/50. The fourth needs to be the same rank as the third, and there are 3 left in the deck, so that's 3/49. Finally, the last card needs to be different from the two already chosen rank, so that's 44/48.

As you can see, these yield different answers.

Thanks

Comment: could you provide the background problem that this is related to? You mention 13 ranks out of nowhere. Is this a standard deck of playing cards? What is the 13 about? Is it a specific card game?

Comment: Consider a deck with two ranks and four suits.  This is so small that you can enumerate all the two-pair hands.  In so doing you are likely to discover the flaws in your approaches to the problem with 13 ranks.  This approach of first tackling a tiny version of a combinatorial problem works very generally to provide insight as well as giving you one or more fully-worked, accurately-answered examples for testing the formulas or code you ultimately develop.